# Mongodb : thread error

Tags: mongodb

I get the following error when I follow the code found in this link :
[MongoDB sample](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/54709368492/how-to-speed-up-mongodb-map-reduce-by-20x)

```
ReferenceError: ScopedThread is not defined (shell):1
```

Meaning should I do one of the following or something else :
 a) Write my own wrapper in python or some other prog lang 
b) Use the ScopedThread or some other API (Thread or ThreadPool etc)
***Just to clarify : This is a problem in the mongo shell and NOT using a Mongo driver or other API outside of the shell.***

Can someone help on this ? 
TIA

Comment: Try the VERY FIRST comment on that, it talks about that

Comment: Sure, but I am not sure what the solution is : What is the API to use ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is still actual..

Thread API may be depend from mongo version installed. I also tried Thread in Mongo 2.2 and it didn't work.
But in MongoDB version 2.4 threads work. I think because new engine V8 was introduced there.